# Lodash sorting object by values, without losing the key

Tags: sorting, key, lodash

Let's say I have an object:

```
{Derp: 17, Herp: 2, Asd: 5, Foo: 8, Qwe: 12}
```

And I need to sort it by value. What I'm looking to get is:

```
{Derp: 17, Qwe: 12, Foo: 8, Asd: 5, Herp: 2}
```

I'd like to use lodash for it. When I use `_.sortBy` it doesn't retain the keys how ever:

```
_.sortBy({Derp: 17, Herp: 2, Asd: 5, Foo: 8, Qwe: 12}).reverse();
// [17, 12, 8, 5, 2]
```

Hell, I'd even settle for just the array of keys, but still sorted by the value in the input:

```
['Derp', 'Herp', 'Foo', 'Asd', 'Qwe']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try like this,

```
_.mapValues(_.invert(_.invert(obj)),parseInt);
```

> Object {Herp: 2, Asd: 5, Foo: 8, Qwe: 12, Derp: 17}

or

```
var obj = {Derp: 17, Herp: 2, Asd: 5, Foo: 8, Qwe: 12}

var result = _.reduceRight(_.invert(_.invert(obj)), function(current, val, key){    
    current[key] = parseInt(val);
    return current;
},{});
```

> Object {Derp: 17, Qwe: 12, Foo: 8, Asd: 5, Herp: 2}

or 
Using Chain methods:

```
_.chain(obj).invert().invert().reduceRight(function(current, val, key){ 
    current[key] = parseInt(val);
    return current;
},{}).value()
```

> Object {Derp: 17, Qwe: 12, Foo: 8, Asd: 5, Herp: 2}

Note: It depends on browser usally object properties order is not gurrantee in most case.

Comment: this will fail if you have non-unique values :P, only one of the non-unique values will be in the resulting object

Answer (score 31):

This worked for me

```
o = _.fromPairs(_.sortBy(_.toPairs(o), 1).reverse())
```

Here's an example:

```js
var o = {
  a: 2,
  c: 3,
  b: 1
};
o = _.fromPairs(_.sortBy(_.toPairs(o), 1).reverse())
console.log(o);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: heads up, this didn't work for me, I had to use frankies instead

Comment: Maybe you need a newer version of lodash? Give an example of how it didn't work. Keep in mind that the author of the original question wanted the values sorted in descending order. If you want them in ascending simply remove the .reverse()

Comment: I think this should be the correct answer.  As the top commenter on the current correct answer states, that solution destroys attributes with similar values if you have non unique values in your object.

Comment: Didn't work as advised, but works like this

o = _.sortBy(_.toPairs(o), 1).reverse()

Answer (score 12):

I was struggling with a similar problem and I was able to solve it doing some transforms with lodash. For your problem it would be:

```
let doo = {Derp: 17, Herp: 2, Asd: 5, Foo: 8, Qwe: 12};

let foo = _.chain(doo)
  .map((val, key) => {
    return { name: key, count: val }
  })
  .sortBy('count')
  .reverse()
  .keyBy('name')
  .mapValues('count')
  .value();

console.log(foo);
// Derp: 17, Qwe: 12, Foo: 8, Asd: 5, Herp: 2 }
```

Comment: This solution works best for me because it works even if there are non-unique values present.

Comment: If your name field is a number this solution will not work for you (haven't found one that can), but this is good elsewise

Answer (score 1):

Vanilla ES6 version

```
const obj = {
  a: 2,
  c: 3,
  b: 1
}

const sorted = Object.entries(obj)
  .sort((a, b) => a[1] <= b[1] ? -1 : 1)
  .reduce((acc, pair) => {
    acc[pair[0]] = pair[1]
    return acc
  }, {})

// Output: { b: 1, a: 2, c: 3 }
```

This'll also let you access the sort callback, allowing for more granular sorting on deeper object properties.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Vanila javascript approch

```js
Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));
```