# Lodash sorting & ordering deep object by values, without losing the key

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'm having a similar need to a previous post on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349838/lodash-sorting-object-by-values-without-losing-the-key) topic: needing to order and sort an object without losing the keys. However, I have an object of objects:

```
var o = { 
  123: { field: "science", name: "zed" },
  234: { field: "tech", name: "sara" },
  672: { field: "arts", name: "jon" }
}

_.fromPairs(_.sortBy(_.toPairs(o),function(a){ return a[1] }).reverse())
```

The above uses the lodash solution mentioned the other topic - I'm however not getting any consistency of results (tho am retaining the key!)

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not clear on what value you intended to sort against above, since objects are incomparable. Let’s say you wanted to sort them by the name field, though — you would find that it still didn’t work.

First some background:

Historically, object properties were considered unordered in ES. The sequence that keys would be enumerated (e.g. by `for ... in` or `Object.keys()`) was implementation-specific.

However enumeration order became a specified behavior in ES2015.

That enumeration order codifies what most engines were already doing:

1. Keys which are integers are enumerated first, from lowest to highest.
2. String keys are enumerated in the order of assignment.
3. Symbol keys are enumerated in the order of assignment.

If you need to use integers as ordered keys, you’ll require a different data structure. `Map` is appropriate:

```js
    const o = { 
      123: { field: "science", name: "zed" },
      234: { field: "tech", name: "sara" },
      672: { field: "arts", name: "jon" }
    }

    const { compare } = new Intl.Collator();

    const res = new Map(Object
      .entries(o)
      .sort(([ , a ], [ , b ]) => compare(a.name, b.name))
    );

    console.log([ ...res ]);
```

If you need to worry about old IE, an array of key-value entries would also suffice.

Comment: This looks great! I need flexibility in what is sorted on, depending on what the user selects. Again, works a charm, thank you!